# Is this question popularity normal?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I was on Code Review, asking a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182932/sort-of-ai-in-c) for the first time. I thought my question was good, but it never crossed my mind that it would become popular enough to make it to the [hot list](https://stackexchange.com). It did, and I want to know why. If there is a good reason why, maybe this could be included in a mandatory tour before asking a first question or something like that. Perhaps I just have good luck. If anyone could enlighten me to I asked a very well received question, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seriously! I ask a question on meta and then it becomes hot! This is crazy!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The algorithm that makes a question hit the *Hot Network Questions* (HNQ) list <s>isn't public AFAIK, but it definitely involves views, votes, answers, and a time factor</s> is documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343).

Your question is indeed a very well-formed CR question: it includes working code, a description of its purpose, a link to the GitHub repository, ...and a somewhat punny title.

A lot of the top CR questions have great, imaginative titles. Everyone asking on this site could title their post "How can I improve this code?" - and some people actually do that (and then get downvotes and comments asking them to edit their annoyingly useless title). But when a title succinctly describes the code's purpose *and* is somewhat funny, what happens next is seldom predictable. Seems that's what happened here.

To answer the nominal question, yes, the popularity of your post is within "normal" range. It's indeed currently in the upper bracket, but there *are* more "popular" questions on the site right now. For the past 48 hours your post is currently:

- #3 highest voted
- #2 most viewed
- #1 most edited

Nothing to worry about for now =)

Comment: Here's a meta.se post about the HNQ algorithm: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343